# How do the direct and inverse image sheaf functors interact with homotopy?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, sheaf-theory

The direct image sheaf functor $f_\ast$ and inverse image sheaf functor $f^\ast$ (here I mean the usual inverse image sheaf functor often denoted by $f^{-1}$) form a well-known adjunction for $\mathsf{Set}$-valued sheaves (I think also for sheaves valued in algebraic categories).

> Is there anything interesting to be said about $f^\ast,g^\ast$ and
>   $f_\ast,g_\ast$ when $f\simeq g$?

**Update:** This question has now been [crossposted to MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/218124/how-do-the-direct-and-inverse-image-sheaf-functors-interact-with-homotopy).